# JQuery .each() skipping even items in array after .shift()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have no idea why they .each is skipping items when I do my display? I can see it is removing properly (or at least I think so) but the displaying is off.

Essentially I want to loop through two arrays with the items being the same, if they are equal dont display them, if not display them and once the inner loop is finished shift off the first item of the first array so that it doesnt display duplicate values (ie: "Jamie | Joe" and  "Joe | Jamie").

I have attached the fiddle. What am I missing here?

```js
peopleA = ['Jamie', 'Joe', 'Jeri', 'Ron', 'Ann']
peopleB = ['Jamie', 'Joe', 'Jeri', 'Ron', 'Ann']

$.each(peopleA, function(i, value) {
  $('#itemsRemoved').append(i + " " + peopleA + "</br>")
  $.each(peopleB, function(j, value2) {
    if (value != value2) {
      $('#items').append(i + " " + value + " | " + j + " " + value2 + "</br>")
    }
  }) // end people B
  peopleA.shift()


}); //end people A
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="items"></p><br>
<p id="itemsRemoved"></p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jamiebrs/gjoo0ovb/

Comment: Each is performing a for loop for you, iterating over the index of the array.  Your internal logic is changing the array it is looping over, potentially corrupting where it's internal index is pointing.

Comment: if(value != value2 && value!= undefined && value2!= undefined){...} check for undefined too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the `shift()` call is amending the array as you loop over it.

You can avoid the problem completely and simplify the logic by looping through a single array. You can then use an inner loop to go through the members which consecutively follow the current one. Using this method there can be no duplicates. Try this:

```js
var people = ['Jamie', 'Joe', 'Jeri', 'Ron', 'Ann'];
people.forEach(function(person, i) {
  for (var j = i + 1; j < people.length; j++) {
    $('#items').append(`<p>${i} ${person} | ${j} ${people[j]}</p>`)
  }
})
```

```css
p { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="items"></p><br>
<p id="itemsRemoved"></p>
```

Comment: No problem glad to help. Note there is still an inner loop here, though.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your intentions, this is the root logic you are after.

```js
var peopleA = ['Jamie', 'Joe', 'Jeri', 'Ron', 'Ann'];
var peopleB = ['Jamie', 'Joe', 'Jeri', 'Ron', 'Ann'];

peopleA.forEach(function(name1, index){
  peopleB.slice(index).forEach(function(name2){
    if (name1 !== name2) {
      console.log(name1, name2);
    }
  });
});
```